# Disable Old dates in date picker

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

i am want to run a promotion(with discount coupons) , so i want to create a Shopping Cart Price Rule  which will start in the future dates (admin shouldn't be able to select the old dates in the "from date" field  ,
everything else is working fine other than disabling old dates in the "from date" field calendar

[image]

[image: Shopping Cart Price Rule]

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

> app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Date.php

*(it is advisable to add custom calendar template, as in any upgrade you will lose your modifications)*

And use the folowing code to disable the previous dates:

```
//<![CDATA[
           var calendarSetupObject = {
                inputField  : "' . $this->getId() . '",
                ifFormat    : "' . $displayFormat . '",
                showsTime   : "' . ($this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false') . '",
                button      : "' . $this->getId() . '_trig",
                align       : "Bl",
                singleClick : true,
                disableFunc: function(date)  {
                    var now= new Date();
                    if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
                    if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
                    if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate())  { return true; } }
                },
            }';
```

[Source](http://amit2k2.blogspot.in/2014/06/magento-disable-past-dates.html)

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply but  it didn't work ,here is the link of screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/u244pc81lxlplkt/from_date.png?dl=0